# Fixed point of cotinuous differentiable function whose derivative is bounded?

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a real continously differentiable function such that $\mid f'(x) \mid \leq 4/5$. Is it true that $f(x) = x$ for some $x$.

My approach:
I took $g(x) = f(x) - x$ and showed that $-9/5 \leq g'(x) \leq -1/5 $ i.e $g(x)$ is a monotonous decreasing function. Now I plan to show that $g(x_1) \geq 0$ for some $x_1$ and $g(x_2) \leq 0$ for some $x_2$ and then use the intermediate value property to conclude that $g(x) = 0$ for some $x$ but I am unable to find such $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know "Banach" Fixed Point Theorem?

**Theorem**
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\exists \delta, 0< \delta <1$ such that $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}, |f(x) - f(y)| \leq \delta |x-y|$, then $\exists! x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_{0}) = x_{0}$.

Now, we also need one more theorem.

**Theorem** (Mean value Theorem)
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a once differentiable function. then $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, \exists c \in \mathbb{R},\, x < c < y$ such that $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = f'(c)$.

To show your function has a fixed point. Fix $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, by mean value theorem we have
$$\bigg|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\bigg| = \bigg|f'(c)\bigg| \leq \frac{4}{5}$$
This implies
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \frac{4}{5}|x-y|$$
Thus, $f$ satisfies the condition of Banach Fixed Point Theorem and $\exists! x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_{0}) = x_{0}$.

Answer (score 4):

You may proceed as follows:

- Choose any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ as a starting value and consider the iteration
- $x_{n+1} =f(x_n)$

It follows
$$\left| x_{n+1} - x_n \right| = \left| f(x_{n}) - f(x_{n-1}) \right| = |f'(\xi_n)|\left| x_{n} - x_{n-1} \right| \leq \frac{4}{5}\left| x_{n} - x_{n-1} \right|$$ 
$$\Rightarrow \left| x_{n+1} - x_n \right| \leq \left(\frac{4}{5} \right)^n \left| x_{1} - x_0 \right|$$
Now, it follows that this sequence converges as
$$x_{n} = x_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n(x_k - x_{k-1}) \mbox{ and } \left|\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k - x_{k-1})\right| <  \left| x_{1} - x_0 \right|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4}{5} \right)^k < \infty$$
Because of continuity of $f$ you have for the limit $x^{\star} = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$
$$\boxed{f(x^{\star}) = x^{\star}}$$